# UnauthorizedAccessException in UWP Directory.CreateDirectory

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

This is a Unity project building to Hololens 2. I'm trying to create a new folder within the Application.PersistentDataPath but it's failing due to UnauthorizedAccessException. Strange thing is it's been working and only recently with seemingly unrelated changes it stopped.

Here's the function that is failing.

```
        static DirectoryInfo EnsureDirectory(string subFolder)
        {   
            Debug.Log($"starting EnsureDirectory() for {subFolder}.");
            
            string directoryPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, subFolder.ValidatePath());
            
            Debug.Log($"About to create directory {directoryPath}");
            var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
            Debug.Log($"Successfully created directory {dir.FullName}");
            
            return dir;
        }
```

At Directory.CreateDirectory I get the error as follows:
[Hololens screenshot of debug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W13MV.jpg)

```
EXCEPTION: UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "C:\" is denied.
```

This error only happens when deployed to the device. In the Unity editor it works perfectly. I also don't know why it would say "C:" when that's not the path I'm trying to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: This is probably because it checks for every path segment, starting with the first one which is root and obviously forbidden. Try `new DirectoryInfo(Application.persistentDataPath).CreateSubdirectory(...);` instead to see if the error vanishes.

Comment: what does `subFolder.ValidatePath()` do? and the `directoryPath` is already wrong ... the `xxxxxxxxx/LocalState` itself already **is** the persistent data path ... you would create a subfolder in there actually ... what do you pass in as `subFolder`? Seems that it is an empty string ...

Comment: @derHugo validate path just removes invalid characters. 
 Sometimes subFolder is empty, in which case I create files directly in the persistent data path. When that string is not empty, it creates a new subfolder. If the folder already exists, createdirectory does nothing. And that's all working in the editor

Comment: well in the Editor you have the permission to create files and folders outside of the application "sandbox" .. on the HoloLens you have not ;) I can only see from your screenshot and the log that the filename itself seems to be empty since it logs e.g. `ValidatePath() with` .. and nothing behind it

Comment: DirectoryInfo(Application.persistentDataPath).CreateSubdirectory(...); doesnt work for me, same error

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @aybe for the answer that did the job.

> This is probably because it checks for every path segment, starting
> with the first one which is root and obviously forbidden. Try new
> DirectoryInfo(Application.persistentDataPath).CreateSubdirectory(...);
> instead to see if the error vanishes